# Modified file not being read over network

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, shared-folders

I have a strange issue with file sharing in Windows Server 2012.

We have an application that's run from a network share. There's also a Terminal Services server so remote users can run it.

This morning we updated it, replacing the .exe file. However, the Terminal Services server is unable to see the new file - opening it launches the old version and the file version information displayed is for the old copy. Obviously it's being cached somewhere, but I can't find any documentation on this feature.

Oddly, the file metadata (size, modified time etc) matches that of the local copy. Copying the file from the network share to a new directory creates a copy of the new file.

Offline files is not enabled and I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Is the file saved on a DFS share? DFS shares can transparently point to multiple file servers, and if one of them doesn't get synchronized, it would deliver an out-of-date version of the file.